# Pandas/Matplotlib histogram issues - x-axis ticks disappearing w subplots and extra unneeded chart space. Tried tight_layout and subplots_adjust

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am having a couple issues plotting Histogram subplots in Matplotlib (this seems Histogram specific; the same with bars and line graphs seem don't seem to have this issue):

1. I can't get the x-axis tick labels to show up on my top 2 charts. In my code below, I haven't once specified the subplots to share x-axis or anything.
   I've also tried this with `plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True)` as well, but it doesn't change the lack of x-axis labels one bit.

   ```
   plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,0], 2, 2)
   ax = firstperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 25)
   plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True) 
   plt.xticks(range(0,26,5), range(0,26,5), rotation="horizontal")
   plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'96 - \'99')
   plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)
   ```

I've noticed that if I plot just the top left histogram, the x-axis ticks actually show up, but disappear as soon as I plot more.

[image]

I've tried adjusting tight_layout as well, `plt.tight_layout(w_pad = 2, h_pad = 2)`, but that doesn't help show my x-axis tick values.

2. subplot seems to leave extra space in some of the charts on the right hand side. How do I get rid of that space and use the whole x-axis for my histogram?

Here is what it the whole thing looks like as is.

[image]

Why are some of the x-axis ticks automatically showing up, and some not? And why do my charts have so much extra space? This isn't an issue when I made a bar chart instead of a histogram... (notice that I've tried adjusting `hspace` and `wspace` in `subplot_adjust` as well).

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Distribution of MegaBall Draws', fontsize=20)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,0], 2, 2)
ax = firstperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 25)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True) 
plt.xticks(range(0,26,5), range(0,26,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'96 - \'99')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [0,2], 2, 2)
secondperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 36)
plt.xticks(range(0,36,5), range(0,41,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'99 - \'02')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,0], 2, 2)
thirdperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 52)
plt.xticks(range(0,55,5), range(0,55,5), rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'02 - \'05')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [2,2], 2, 2)
fourthperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 46)
plt.xticks(range(0,50,5), range(0,50,5),rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'05 - \'13')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.subplot2grid((6,4), [4,1], 2, 2)
fifthperiod.megaball.plot(kind='hist', bins = 15)
plt.xticks(rotation="horizontal")
plt.title('Megaball Distrib \'13 - ')
plt.ylabel("# of draws", fontsize = 10)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad = 2, h_pad = 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.8, wspace = 0.75, hspace = 2.5)
plt.savefig("megaball_distribs.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It looks like you're using a style - what happens when you use the matplotlib defaults?  Also, try reproducing with some fake data to give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Ajean what style are you referring to?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you're using pandas - that would explain the gray background and white gridlines (pandas uses a particular style when it plots DataFrames).  You're also using pyplot while also plotting via each DataFrame (Series?) instead of using the matplotlib objects directly.  I imagine that the latter will work more consistently.

Comment: @Ajean - what would be the way to use matplotlib objects directly? All I know is that I have some Pandas series that I would like to chart in a histogram. I thought pandas was supposed to nicely be integrated with matplotlib? It works just fine when I make bar/line charts with the same pandas series, seems to be a histogram-specific issue...

Comment: pandas *is* tightly integrated with matplotlib - the fact that you've made some (other than your funny x-axes) nice plots with it illustrates that.  However, there are still all kinds of funny edge cases that cause funny behavior, especially if you mix two paradigms (in this case, pandas plotting and pyplot).  In your case, perhaps try passing the axes objects returned by subplot2grid (e.g. `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(...)`), into your plot (e.g. `series.plot(..., ax=ax1)`)

Comment: As a general tip, I know there are all kinds of tutorials/examples out there that use `plt.plot` for everything (`plt.xlabel()`, `plt.imshow()`...), but for actual programmatic plotting, moving away from pyplot and using the object methods directly (`ax.plot`, `ax.set_xlabel()`) will make your life ten times easier.

Comment: For this particular problem I can't test my supposition because your example is not runnable (hint hint ;) ), but it's still good advice :).

Comment: @Ajean - I've created a MCVE code, and the same problem comes up. mind taking a quick look?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79715/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-ajean).

Comment: awesome question...though you should have include imports... and version of pandas..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a funny effect that appears to be present in pandas 0.16.0.  Upgrading to 0.16.1 fixes it.